# How to adapt code among view types?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to use a sap.m.List Control in a application, however, I am struggling to find examples of how to implement this control in a JavaScript View. I am aware that the "Explored" app has [code examples](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListItemTypes/code) to implement the controls in XML views; However, I would like to know how to adapt those examples to HTML, JSON and JavaScript views. What an expert UI5 Developer does when he needs to adapt a control from a XML View to another type of view? Do we have any guidelines? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the guidelines you`ll find at least a quick introduction on js-views in the demokit documentation [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f262ef6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html).

I created a pretty simple example for the sap.m.List in javascript [here](http://jsbin.com/kuguqisuka/13/edit?html,output) although I am aware that it is not part of a view, but it should give you a first impression.

If you are looking for more js examples have a look [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#content/Controls/index.html). For the older sap.ui.commons controls all samples are created with javascript.